# SQL : Joining two time series data and computing totals and ratios from a given point in time

Tags: sql, time-series

For my project, I have two data sets/series. One is my customers by registration date and another is the billing per month for each customer. The first series starts off in 2012 and the second starts off in Jan 2017 (... no requirement to look before that for my analysis).

Table 1 :

```
 Customer_ID     , Registration_date 
  AB123           , 2012-02-01
  CD345           , 2012-05-01 
  GH987           , 2018-06-01 
  etc.
```

Table 2:

```
Calendar_month      , Customer_ID      , Revenues 
2017-01-01          ,  AB123           ,   $99 
2018-01-01          ,  AB123           ,   $97
2019-01-01          ,  AB123           ,   $104 
2017-01-01          ,  GH987           ,   $92 
2018-01-01          ,  GH987           ,   $101
2019-01-01          ,  GH987           ,   $98 
etc.
```

(non-billers just won't appear here e.g. CD345)

The objective: I would like to have a table with on the columns the timeline (calendar_month) and on the rows, two measures:

1. the total number of customers registered up until Jan 2017, then incrementing with new customers registered each month until the latest month (here August 2019)
2. the total number of customers billing above a certain threshold (let's say $100) in each calendar month, including historical customers before Jan-2017.  
   (a third row ideally with the ratio of item #2 over #1 above)

I joined the two tables on Customer_ID and Calendar_month <= Registration_date. 
However this allows me to see only the new registrations per month/year - I can't seem to capture the historical registrations (and aggregate them at 2017-01-01), nor can I get their billing info.

Joining only on Customer_ID makes the other non-billing customers non visible (and therefore not accounted for in the total registered customer count) .

Any ideas / help you could provide will be much appreciated.